# How to retrieve the specific records that failed using create()/insertMany() on Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to retrieve the specific record that failed for the non-WriteErrors. I've tried using `db.collection.create(req.body, {ordered: false})` and `db.collection.insertMany(req.body, {ordered: false}}`. I've also tried looking with `aggregateErrors: true` or `rawResult: true`, but still unsuccessful

For the WriteErrors, i.e Duplicate Keys, I found the 'errmsg' and 'op' that shows the actual record that failed to be inserted

```
"writeErrors": [{
    "err": {
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.collection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: \"0000010\" }",
        "op": {
            "system": "Dev",
            "user": "00000980",
            "item": "0010",
            ...
        }
    }
}]
```

I'm looking for a way to get something similiar but for the ValidationErrors, i.e. incorrect key name, wrong data type, etc.
So far I'm only able to catch the error message and the path/value, but I haven't found something similar to the 'op' from the WriteErrors

```
{
    "errors": {
        "system": {
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "message": "QA is not a valid system",
            "properties": {
                "message": "QA is not a valid system",
                "type": "user defined",
                "path": "system",
                "value": "QA"
            },
            "kind": "user defined",
            "path": "system",
            "value": "QA"
        }
    },
    "_message": "collection validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "collection validation failed: system: QA is not a valid system"
}
```

Is there a way to get the error message + the specific record that failed for the ValidationErrors/non-WriteErrors?

Thanks in advance!